# How to append a dynamically created div to another dynamically created div?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a dynamically created `div` to another dynamically created `div`, but I keep getting an error in the Chromium JavaScript console that says "Cannot Call method `appendChild` of undefined. I'm not sure why this is happening. Here is the code that I used:

```
for(var i=3; i < 8; i++)
{
      var parent_div = document.createElement('div');
      parent_div.setAttribute('class',"bottom_block left");
      document.body.appendChild(parent_div); //Append parent_div to body. This works fine

      var child_div = document.createElement('div');
      child_div.setAttribute('class', "content SA");
      child_div.setAttribute('id', "SA"+i);
      document.parent_div.appendChild(child_div); // This is 
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `document.parent_div.appendChild()` use `parent_div.appendChild()`.

`document.parent_div` is looking for the `parent_div` property of the `document` whereas `parent_div` is the variable referencing the div you just added.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Great! Glad to help! Don't forget to accept this as the correct answer since it helped you; that way other people with a similar issue will be able to find the answer :) Good luck!